# How to perform Left Anti Join in AWS Athena DB? or any alternative to it?

Tags: amazon-athena

How to do left anti join in AWS Athena DB? I have googled it and i didn't get any help. Or any alternative solution would be appreciated.

I have 2 tables emp and dept and i want to do left anti join with these tables using columns "emp_dept_id" and "dept_id".

[image: tables can be seen on below image]

I need a query for Athena.

Comment: Please include sample data and desired results.

Comment: I just wanted to know that, is it possible to do Left -anti join in Athena? if yes, can i have syntax for it. else is there any alternate solution to do Left-anti in Athena?

Comment: Yes it is possible.  Please add some sample data to make this a concrete question.

Comment: sample data added

Comment: Could you please explain this line? "WHERE d.dept_id IS NULL". What is it's significance exactly? @TimBiegeleisen

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a left anti-join query per your request:

```sql
SELECT e.*
FROM Emp e
LEFT JOIN Dept d
    ON d.dept_id = e.emp_dept_id
WHERE d.dept_id IS NULL;
```

Note that you could also express the above using exists logic:

```sql
SELECT e.*
FROM Emp e
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM Dept d
    d.dept_id = e.emp_dept_id
);
```

Comment: Could you please explain this line? "WHERE d.dept_id IS NULL". What is it's significance exactly? Tim

Comment: When that null condition is true, it means that the record from the table on the left side of the join did _not_ match to any record on the right table.  This is the "anti" join.